# How to convert list of items into json parent-child hierarchy?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, text-processing

I have some items in a list with points, sub-points and sub-sub points need to pass all of them into json in parent-child hierarchy.

I tried as each point made it to list, if a point consist of point, sub or sub-sub-point all becomes in one list  of a point.

my list appears like this:

```
lst=["1. content","(a) content","(b) ","(i)","(ii"),"(c)","2.","3.","(A)","(B)","4."]
```

```
for ptags in soup.findAll('p'):
                lst.append(ptags.get_text())

    regex = r"^\([a-z]\)\s.*"
    regex1=r"^\([\D]+\)\s.*"
    j=0
    sub = []
    for i in lst:
        if sub:
            match = re.match(regex, i)
            match1=re.match(regex1,i)
            if match:
                sub.append(i)
            elif match1:
                sub.append(i)
            else:
                j=j+1
                sub = [i]
            Notes[str(j)] = sub
        else:
            if sub:
                Notes[str(j)] = sub
            sub = [i]
            Notes[str(j)] = i

I need the json hierarchy as output in this way :
```

```
"1. content",
       "(a) content",
       "(b) ",
             "(i)",
             "(ii"),
       "(c)",
"2.",
"3.",
    "(A)",
    "(B)",

"4."

######################################JSON STRUCTURE
[
  {
    "1. content": [
      "(a) content",
      {
        "(b) ": [
          "(i)",
          "(ii)"
        ]
      },
      "(c)"
    ]
  },
  "2.",
  {
    "3.": [
      "(A)",
      "(B)"
    ]
  },
  "4."
]
```

Comment: unless you create a class with attributes (= your sub points) and parse the instance of the class to json, I think you will have to write your own method interpretation of list to json - based solely on the given list above, you have no structure given other than "numbers are the main object" and "between numbers are different styled sub- and subsub-items".  For json parsing you need some kind of structure that python also recognizes and is not theoretically based.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a similar hierarchy, you should change your data to a `dict`. Because you did not include enough information in your code, I just add a sample of what your data should look like:

```
from json import dumps
lst = [{"1. content": ["(a) content", {"(b) ": ["(i)","(ii)"]},"(c)"]},"2.",{"3.": ["(A)","(B)"]},"4."]
```

Each hierarchy level should be a dictionary. For elements those have no children, you can pass them as a simple list element.

You can get your json string using `dumps` now:

```
dumps(lst)
```

Comment: yes, exactly i need output in the structure, i have passed every thing into list. i'm not sure how to make difference between them and make as hierarchy

Comment: Can you add the code that generates your list into your question?

Comment: ```
for ptags in soup.findAll('p'):
                lst.append(ptags.get_text())
```
This is the code which generates my list. i created ptags to pass it to list ,that was all are siblings no hierarchy

Comment: I can not understand, `p` tags those you want to show hierarchically are siblings and there is no hierarchy in your data?